# PyCharm: Variable in finally block might be referenced before assignment?

Tags: python, python-2.7, exception, pycharm

**PyCharm** warns me that variable `category` can be referenced before assignment but I don't think so.

Except should catch every `Exception` (except fatal errors) and finally is called after `try` or `except` block.

```
    try:
        category = lst[2]
    except:
        category = None
    finally:
        if not category: #here
            category = self.default_category
```

[image]

What do you think? Is it true or is it a bug?

Comment: Maybe a bug. I'd see if assigning None to category before the try removes the warning. What is the underline on `except`?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps PyCharm is seeing the assignment without considering, "assignment to what".  That is, the `None` is what makes the difference, consider if you instead wrote:

```
try:
    category = lst[2]
except:
    category = Noone
finally:
    if not category:
        category = self.default_category
```

(Or `None/1`, etc.) Then you'd get:

```
NameError: name 'category' is not defined
```

as there would be an exception in the exception if `lst` were empty:

> When an exception has occurred in the try clause and has not been
>   handled by an except clause (or it has occurred in an except or else
>   clause), it is re-raised after the finally clause has been executed.

Comment: This seems to be the likely cause. Pycharm is thinking "what if the `try` raises an exception before the first assignment, and then the `except` also raises an exception before the second assignment? Then `if not category` will fail".